# I can not get CV2.waitKey in OpenCV to work properly. After running waitKey the code get unresponsive

Tags: python, opencv, spyder, freeze

I ran this simple code to show a pic using OpenCV. The pic shows up in a new windows as expected. When I close the window the console in spyder get stuck, it looks like is still running or waiting. It seams like the waitKey() in not working properly. The only way I can continue is restarting the console.
When I use a number for example waitKey(1000) the program works fine, the picture shows up, windows close and the program finish as expected.
I tried to run the code in the Anaconda shell from the prompt and I have the same problem 
I am using python 3.7.5
Thanks a lot!

```
import cv2
cv2.imshow("title", img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Use cv2.waitKey(0)

Comment: @fmw42 zero is the default. what's the point??

Comment: I used cv2.waitKey(0) and it is the same as zero is the default. Only when I use another number works, but it is not what I intent to do. Thanks for the help

Comment: Perhaps you may have had multiple image windows opened due to console restarting, or manually closed windows before the console took care of it causing it to become confused. The command works properly for everyone else. I can suggest you to install VSCode and use the step-by-step debug functions to see what's happening, Spyder isn't the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I tried cv2.waitKey(0) and did not work either. that is the default. I restart the pc and tried with one pic open still shows the same problem.  I did installed VSCode and tried in there. I had the same problem. it is like  cv2.destroyAllWindows() gets hung up

Answer (score 2):

Before hitting a key get focus on graphic window with the image.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble. My Jupyter needs to restart the kernel after each run. I transferred everything in a terminal and executed 'python3 my.py'. The prog got stuck again, never coming back to the linux prompter. Keyboard interruption not working. I'm forced to close the terminal window and open it again (probably similar restarting kernel in Jupyter). No such problem in Windows 11